# Command for toggling mouse emulation

Tags: linux, xfce

In Xfce, one can use the numpad on the keyboard as a mouse by enabling mouse emulation in *Settings* > *Accessibility* > *Mouse* tab > *Use mouse emulation*.

I want to toggle the feature with a shortcut key when I need to. What is the command to switch the feature on and off?

Answer (score 1):

From https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=30416#p30416  (from ToZ, Thank you!)

First turn on mouse emulation in the accessibility section in the Settings Manager.

Then:

Create a script with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $(xfconf-query -c accessibility -p /MouseKeys) == "false" ] \
    && $(xfconf-query -c accessibility -p /MouseKeys -s true) \
    || $(xfconf-query -c accessibility -p /MouseKeys -s false)
```

And make the script executable (`chmod +x ./script.sh`)

Assign it to the Alt+Numlock key combination:

- Go to the whisker menu -> Settings Manager -> Keyboard
- In here select the "Application Shortcuts" tab
- Select `Add`, choose your script
- Set the shortcut combination by pressing alt+num lock or whatever works